# Vagrant doesn't share my folders?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, shared-directory

I am using scotch box, for starters but consider the following:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "scotch/box"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.25"
    config.vm.hostname = "scotchbox"
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]

    # Optional NFS. Make sure to remove other synced_folder line too
    # config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"] }

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.memory = 1536
    end

end
```

Now consider the following folder:

[image]

Now consider the following after doing `vagrant up && vagrant ssh` then `cd /var/www`:

```
vagrant@scotchbox:/var/www$ ls
vagrant@scotchbox:/var/www$
```

Where is `public/` and `html/`? I have tried the nfs method and still nothing. **Ideas**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try to do :

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
```

or use an absolute path.

One of the reason is that `.` is already mapped to `/vagrant` on the VM. You can check in the output of `vagrant up` the shared folder that are mapped. so depending how vagrant is doing with the order of synced folder it can map its `vagrant` folder so the `.` will be mapped with `/vagrant` and not the `/var/www`

If the existing `/vagrant` is the issue and you're not using you can add

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
```